# How to see all my comments on idb file

Tags: ida, windows, exe

I add some comments to exe file with ida(save on idb).

Is there any simple way how to see all my comments in 1 windows?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is IDA Marker.

**Alt+M** to make a marked comment at current cursor location

**Ctrl+M** to bring up a window showing all marked comments

Comment: That help if I already marked ... I have lot of comments tgat I not narked, and I want to watch them all

Comment: Script it. Interface with IDAPython to iterate every single instruction and use GetCommentEx to see if there's already a comment there. If there is, print out the address, instruction, and comment

Comment: I had never do it, can you tell me please how to do it/ link me to place that explain  same thing??

Comment: Just Google for IDAPython tutorials. The only prior knowledge u need is Python

Comment: I'm amazed there isn't just a "Comments" dialog that has a list of your comments.  If you've commented against a line you're instinctively quite likely to want to go back there.  Especially considering the eyewatering price of IDA this seems like a basic feature that's lacking.